# Making Built-in render decals

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a project that really needs decals (built-in render). Well, that's it. I tried to make a shader with Shader Graph, but it got almost worse. Please help me find a way to make a decal out of an object (cube)

Tried to make shader with Shader Graph. Played with textures and materials